# Declaración de Constantes en PHP

Tags: php, php5

No solo tenemos la posibilidad de usar variables; que son valores que tendrán un valor inicial y cuando sean ocupados en alguna función/método se verán afectadas y por lo tanto su valor cambiará.

Sin embargo al momento de tener valores que son constantes o que su valor no se verá alterado aunque se utilicen en una o múltiples operaciones; esas son `constantes`

Tenemos 2 formas de definir constantes en PHP:

1. Declarándolas a través del método `DEFINE()`, donde el primer parámetro es el nombre de la constante y el segundo es el valor asignado a esta

Ejemplo

```
define('IVA', 16);
```

2. A través de la keyword `const`

   `const IVA = 16;`

Sin embargo ¿dónde se debe aplicar cada una de estas mismas o ambas son correctas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las constantes se pueden declarar a través de 2 contextos; tanto en el

1. contexto global, usando `DEFINE()`, lo cual me va a facilitar su uso fuera del alcance de una clase declarada lo que me va a permitir tenerla disponible para otras y la propia

Ejemplo

```
<?php

define('IVA', 16);

class Example
{

}
```

---

```
//esto es correcto
<?php

class Example{
    const IVA = 16;

    function dimeIVA(){
        return self::IVA;
    }
}

echo Example::IVA;
```

2. A un alcance local, haciendo uso de la keyword `const` y declarandolas a nivel del cuerpo de la clase donde estará contenida

Ejemplo.

```
<?php

class Example
{
const IVA = 16;
}
```

Además de lo anterior, la declaración de `const` en un condicional no es válido mientras que define() es aceptado

```
//esto es válido
<?php

if(1 === 1){
    define("IVA", 19);
    echo IVA;
}
```

---

```
//esto no es válido
<?php

if(1 === 1){
    const "IVA" = 19;
    echo IVA;
}
```

> Las declaraciones de constantes globales no son recomendadas de manera
>   generalizada, pues su declaración y valor pudiera entrar en conflicto
>   con otras partes del código escrito

Del mismo modo en la declaración de `const` puedes asignarle un valor o un arreglo de valores; del modo siguiente

```
const PAGOS = [123, 56.7, 1234.33];
print_r(PAGOS);
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 56.7 [2] => 1234.33 )
```

Del mismo modo en la declaración `define()` a partir de PHP 7 puedes asignarle mas de un valor a una constante; del modo siguiente

```
define('PAGOS', array(
    123,
    1233.67,
    2333
));

print_r(PAGOS);
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 1233.67 [2] => 2333 )
```

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.define.php